# Bind across templates

Tags: aurelia

At app.html I'm drawing a breadcrumb 
Breadcrumb template

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li repeat.for="crumb of breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb-item ${$last ? 'active' : ''}">
        ${crumb.name}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Now, I would like to define a different value for "breadcrumb" property for each page. But I would prefer to call the breadcrumb template only once, at app.html.

```
export class PageA {
  breadcrumb = ['parentA', 'childA']
  constructor () {
  }
}

export class PageB {
  breadcrumb = ['parentB', 'childB']
  constructor () {
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare your breadcrumb custom element in the app.html view (rather than in each separate page view) and bind its breadcrumb property to the values you declare in child pages, the most straight forward solution is to use a separate singleton service that holds the breadcrumb data.

For example:

```
import { singleton } from "aurelia-framework";

@singleton()
export class BreadcrumbService {
    breadcrumb = [];
}
```

Inject it into your breadcrumb.js like so:

```
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework"
import { BreadcrumbService } from "./breadcrumb-service";

@inject(BreadcrumbService)
export class Breadcrumb{
    constructor(breadcrumbService) {
        this.breadcrumbService = breadcrumbService;
    }
}
```

With a slight modification to your breadcrumb.html:

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li repeat.for="crumb of breadcrumbService.breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb-item ${$last ? 'active' : ''}">
                ${crumb.name}
            </li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</template>
```

Then in each child page you would inject the BreadcrumbService and modify its breadcrumb property, which automatically updates the value in your breadcrumb.js:

```
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework"
import { BreadcrumbService } from "breadcrumb-service";

@inject(BreadcrumbService)
export class PageA {
    constructor(breadcrumbService) {
        breadcrumbService.breadcrumb = ['parentA', 'childA'];
    }
}

@inject(BreadcrumbService)
export class PageB {
    constructor() {
        breadcrumbService.breadcrumb = ['parentB', 'childB'];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You might have to force a binding refresh on the repeat.for by first splicing the breadcrumb array on the breadcrumb service each time before changing it in your childpages, the target binding might not update when you set the array to a different value. This is because repeat.for uses a collection observer that listens to .splice() etc, but does not check for array object reference equality.

You could encapsulate this in the BreadcrumbService:

```
import { singleton, TaskQueue, inject } from "aurelia-framework";

@singleton()
@inject(TaskQueue)
export class BreadcrumbService {
    breadcrumb = [];

    constructor(taskQueue) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    setBreadcrumb(breadcrumb) {
        this.breadcrumb.splice(0);

        // Using a micro task gives the repeat.for an opportunity to respond to the .slice() before setting the new values
        this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
            this.breadcrumb.push(breadcrumb);
        });
    }
}
```

And in your child pages:

```
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework"
import { BreadcrumbService } from "breadcrumb-service";

@inject(BreadcrumbService)
export class PageA {
    constructor(breadcrumbService) {
        breadcrumbService.setBreadcrumb(['parentA', 'childA']);
    }
}

@inject(BreadcrumbService)
export class PageB {
    constructor() {
        breadcrumbService.setBreadcrumb(['parentB', 'childB']);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is  ${crumb.name} defined? Please update the code.